# PPI + Server2go

Tags: php, doctrine, ppi, server2go

I am having a problem getting PPI framework to run on Server2go.

How do you use a port? for example 172.0.0.1:4001 in the datasource.config.php of PPI.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running PPI Framework v2.0, and that the database driver you're using on the PPI Datasource component is MySQL, then you're actually talking to a Doctrine DBAL connection, as such you can reference the Doctrine DBAL documentation.

As per this section here on their docs:
http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pdo-mysql

You would specify the port number like this:

```
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'host' => '172.0.0.1',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'port' => 4001
);
```

Please do let me know if you're not using PPI Framework 2.0 or not using MySQL, then the answer may be a bit different.